# How to write normal sql query into laravel 5.2 format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How to write my sql query in laravel 5.2, query is giving below

```
    SELECT a.groupID, count( * ) AS totalCount,  b.description
    FROM devicelist AS a, devicegroup AS b
    WHERE a.groupID = b.groupID
    GROUP BY a.groupID
```

Comment: Have you ever read laravel documentation? Please read it first then ask the question or google it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = DB::table('devicelist as a')
  ->join('devicegroup as b', 'a.groupID', '=', 'b.groupID')
  ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, a.groupID, b.description'))
  ->groupBy('a.groupID')
  ->get();
```